# Previous/Next with the same category

Tags: shortcode

I have this code to use with shortcode at my portfolio pages.

Everything is working fine, but I need that next and previous get the same category.

This is the code:

```
add_shortcode( 'prev', 'prev_shortcode' );
add_shortcode( 'next', 'next_shortcode' );
function next_shortcode($atts) {
    global $post;
    ob_start(); 
    next_post_link( '<div class="nav-next">%link</div>', 'Next project' );              
    $result = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $result;
}

function prev_shortcode($atts) {
    global $post;
    ob_start();
    previous_post_link( '<div class="nav-previous">%link</div>', 'Previous project' );              
    $result = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`next_post_link()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link) accepts a third argument which will limit the links to the same category. There is an example of this usage in the Codex:

```
next_post_link( '%link', 'Next post in category', TRUE );
```

> in_same_term
>
> (*boolean*) (*optional*) Indicates whether
>   next post must be within the same taxonomy term as the current post.
>   If set to 'true', only posts from the current taxonomy term
>   will be displayed. If the post is in both the parent and subcategory,
>   or more than one term, the next post link will lead to the next post
>   in any of those terms.
>
> - true
> - false
>
> Default: false

What you need, in short, is to add `, TRUE` to you function arguments:

```
next_post_link( '<div class="nav-next">%link</div>', 'Next project', TRUE );
```

And:

```
previous_post_link( '<div class="nav-previous">%link</div>', 'Previous project', True );
```

Comment: I was expecting that you could help me modify my code ir order to do what i need. The code is working great, just need to add category. I do not understand PHP at all. Tks

Comment: @Advert-u : I did help you modify the code. Add `, TRUE` to your arguments. If you don't understand PHP "at all" why are you writing PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Buffering should always always be used as your last resort, plus one though for trying to return your shortcode output. As you already know, `next_post_link()` and `previous_post_link()` echos its results to screen, but we need to return the output from these in order to avoid unexpected output.

These two functions simply echos what is returned from [`get_next_post_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_next_post_link/) and [`get_previous_post_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_previous_post_link/) respectively, so this will be the functions to use in your shortcode

Example:

```
add_shortcode( 'prev', 'prev_shortcode' );
add_shortcode( 'next', 'next_shortcode' );
function next_shortcode() {
    global $post;
    $result = get_next_post_link( '<div class="nav-next">%link</div>', 'Next project' );              

    return $result;
}

function prev_shortcode() {
    global $post;
    $result = get_previous_post_link( '<div class="nav-previous">%link</div>', 'Previous project' );              

    return $result;
}
```

I do however have a few concerns here, and that is, why do you need this to run from a shortcode. You are most probably going to use this in a single post page using `do_shortcode()` to execute the shortcode. You need to remember, shortcodes needs to be parsed, which in turn wastes time and resources (*although it might be only a minute amount*). Shortcodes should only be used in the page editor's WYSIWYG editor. If you are using shortcodes anywhere but there (*that is, using `do_shortcode()`*), you are doing it wrong.

You can just simply use `next_post_link()` and `previous_post_link()` as is in your template. It is faster and better.

Example:

```
next_post_link( '<div class="nav-next">%link</div>', 'Next project' ); 
previous_post_link( '<div class="nav-previous">%link</div>', 'Previous project' );
```

Apart from what @s_ha_dum has said about setting the third parameter to `true`, you also need to set the fifth parameter to the taxonomy the terms belongs to if the terms does not belong to the build in taxonomy `category`.

So, for the build in taxonomy `category`, you would do

```
next_post_link( '<div class="nav-next">%link</div>', 'Next project', true ); 
previous_post_link( '<div class="nav-previous">%link</div>', 'Previous project', true );
```

and for a custom taxonomy, you would do

```
next_post_link( '<div class="nav-next">%link</div>', 'Next project', true, '', 'MY_TAXONOMY' ); 
previous_post_link( '<div class="nav-previous">%link</div>', 'Previous project', true, '', 'MY_TAXONOMY' );
```

where `MY_TAXONOMY` is the name of your custom taxonomy

Comment: About your question: I need to run from a shortcode because I use a theme with a layout builder. I need to put the shortcode [prev] and [next] inside the portfolio page in a specific place. As i told before php is new to me. So what i did was looking for a away to do it. I found this code here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12904/making-a-shortcode-next-and-previous-to-place-into-specific-posts-for-post-n, and i'm trying to make it work. I add the code you gave me but, not working.

Comment: That code is not correct, you cannot use `next_post_link` and `previous_post_link`. Shortcodes should **never** use code that echos output. That is why I said, use `get_netx_post_link` as in my answer. Please reread my answer

Comment: What do you mean by *not working*

Comment: All you need to do is to properly implement the code. I have given you the basics (*so did @s_ha_dum*). We do expect that you at least know the basics to help yourself. We are not here to do everything for you.

Comment: I understand that. All i have to say is thank you.